# (Selenium/Python) Help clicking a button with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I'm writing a script that transfers tickets for an event.

Here is a snippet of the UI:

[UI snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vc84b.png)

Here is the HTML DOM for seat 5 for reference:

```
<div ng-repeat="ticket in transferableTickets track by $index" ng-hide="busyLoadingSeats" ng-click="selectSeat(ticket)" class="circle ng-scope clickable" ng-class="{'selected' : ticket.selected, 'clickable': ticket.TransferStatusId === 1 || ticket.TransferStatusId === 10, 'active' : ticket.TransferStatusId === 10, 'disabled' : ticket.TransferStatusId !== 1 &amp;&amp; ticket.TransferStatusId !== 10 }">
                            <span class="ng-binding">5</span>
                            <div ng-hide="ticket.TransferStatusId == 1 || ticket.TransferStatusId == 10" class="ng-hide">
                                <a ng-show="$index % 13 < 3" class="clickable ng-isolate-scope" trigger="hover" placement="right" tm-popup="" content="">?</a>
                                <a ng-show="$index % 13 >= 3 &amp;&amp; $index % 13 <= 10" class="clickable ng-isolate-scope ng-hide" trigger="hover" placement="bottom" data-width="300" tm-popup="" content="">?</a>
                                <a ng-show="$index % 13 > 10" class="clickable ng-isolate-scope ng-hide" trigger="hover" placement="left" tm-popup="" content="">?</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

The seat numbers will vary and there not always be only 2 seats on a page, so a generic xpath doesn't seem to work.

What has worked for me so far is:

```
web.find_element_by_xpath('//div[span[text()="' + str(seat_click) + '"]]').click()
```

Where 'seat_click' is the seat number. However, for some reason it does **not** work when the 'seat_click' = 9 for some god forsaken reason (there have been several cases and all seat ranges beginning with 9 always fail). So I'm figuring I must try a different approach.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the page? Picture doesn't help at all.

Comment: I've updated with the full frame. This is what pops up. I have no problem filling out the forms or clicking the non "9" buttons. There is no link to give you as it is a site that requires a login